# When to use on-click or on-tap w/ Polymer?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I've researched a lot but still haven't found a good answer. When should I use `on-click` and when `on-tap`, specifically w/ Polymer?

This guide focuses on programmatic event listeners, so isn't helpful in that regard:

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/touch.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `on-tap` all the time, because the semantics of `on-tap` are better aligned with mobile devices than `on-click`.

For example, `on-click` does not fire if another finger is touching the screen, or if the element directly under the finger does not have a mouse handler. There are also some complications with getting `on-click` to work while you are scrolling. Use `on-tap` unless there is a compelling reason not to.

Comment: note in polymer 2.0, "The tap event is included in the gesture event mixin for backwards compatibility, but it's no longer required in modern mobile browsers", see [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events)

Answer (score 1):

In [Polymer 2 documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events) and [Polymer 3 documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events), using **on-click** event is suggested. on-tap is legacy.

Comment: The warning is now also on the Polymer 3 documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the legacy on-tap anymore since this is deprecated in Polymer 2 and 3.
See https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events